# Bootstrap 4 - IE 8 & 9 comptability issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 with MVC application and on Internet Explorer 8 or 9 all elements are jumbled with compatibility issues
even after putting html shiv and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Is there a workaround to fix the compatibility issue.

Comment: ...People are still supporting IE 8? That's just masochism.

Comment: Microsoft has ended support for Internet Explorer versions less than 11 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support).  You need to convince your customers that they are putting themselves at great security risk by running a completely unsupported browser

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 9 and lower are not supported by Bootstrap 4. See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer

Comment: I know the official bootstrap documents but i am looking for workaround

Comment: @Melodie - the workaround would be either to a) not use Bootstrap or b) not use < IE 11

Comment: Bootstrap 3 apparently supports older IEs. So there's that option. But yeah. Latest features and such, or compatibility with old and busted browsers. Pick one.

Comment: @cHao Thank you

Comment: @Tommy i found libraries on GitHub that fixes the compatibility issue and it worked on IE 8/9